# Iterate over inner array gives error with foreach

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, nested-loops

I have nested array in JSON structure and I am trying to iterate over inner array using foreach but it gives **error** as

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
```

**JSON structure**

```
 "outerArray": [
        {
           
            "innerArray": [
                {
                    "id1": "1",
                    "id2": "2",
                    "id3": "3"
                }
            ],
             "prop1": "2",
             "prop2": "test",
        }
    ]
```

**Code**

```
outerArray.forEach(function(item, index) {
     
            let innerList = outerArray[index].innerArray
            if( innerList && innerList != undefined) {
                innerList.forEach(function(itemInner, indexInner {  //error 
                    itemInner.id1 = (itemInner.id1.value && itemInner.id1.value != undefined) ? itemInner.id1.value :
                itemInner.id1;
                    itemInner.id2 = (itemInner.id2.value && itemInner.id2.value != undefined) ? itemInner.id2.value :
                itemInner.id1;
                });
            }
        outerArray[index].innerArray = innerList;
    });
```

Please let me know what is wrong in traversing logic.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you want to do in outerArray[index].innerArray = innerList; ?

Comment: I have updated the question with the comment where error rises, I am assigning manipulated inner array to the outer array

Comment: you are using `itemInner.id1.value` and there is no `value` property on `id`

Comment: id1 and id2 are drop down fields , so if values are newly entered then I need to take from 'form' drop down 'value' and map it to id1 and id2 .For simplicity, I removed full code. But it is not even reaching inside the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an opening parenthesis after `indexInner` on that line:

```
innerList.forEach(function(itemInner, indexInner {  //error
```

```js
let outerArray = [
        {      
            "innerArray": [
                {
                    "id1": "1",
                    "id2": "2",
                    "id3": "3"
                }
            ],
             "prop1": "2",
             "prop2": "test",
        }
    ];
 
outerArray.forEach(function(item, index) {
  let innerList = outerArray[index].innerArray;
  if(innerList) {
    innerList.forEach(function(itemInner, indexInner) {  // <-- Need ( 
      itemInner.id1 = itemInner.id1.value ;
      itemInner.id2 = itemInner.id2.value ;
    });
  }
  outerArray[index].innerArray = innerList;
});
```

Comment: sorry scott. While rewriting code for this post , missed the parenthesis.It exist in the main code and code compiles well.